# Android Maven Plugin & SDK Version

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to set up building of a minimal Android application via Maven. It works but I am not sure about the dependency on Google Android Library.

Here is the important part of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0</version>
          <configuration>
              <sdk>
                  <platform>23</platform>
              </sdk>
              <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
          </configuration>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I would like to support API Level 16 as the Minimum API Level and Target API Level should be 23.

What should be the appropriate version of artifact `android` in group `com.google.android`?

Why the newest version of this artifact is more than 3 years old (version 4.1.1.4 released on Aug-2012)?
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/android

Is the element `build/plugins/plugin/configuration/sdk/platform` with value `23` correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Why maven? Why not gradle? Gradle is the recommended build system

Comment: @nadish-a Indeed. However, Maven is a valid option to build an Android aplication. Last version of Android Maven Plugin was released on 2014-06-15 and another version is developed. This means that this project is alive and there should be a clear answer to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK 4.1.1.4 is the last version that is available as an artifact in central Maven repository. Artifacts for newer versions can be created in local Maven repository using the following tool:
https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer